# Simplify T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I would like to simplify this query if possible.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(tDateTimeOfSurvey) 
FROM 
    Stocks.dbo.tblSurvey
WHERE
    (   
       (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tWetTons), 0) 
        FROM Stocks.dbo.tblSurvey 
        WHERE tStockAreaID = 3
          AND tDateTimeOfSurvey BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20140228') + 
      (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tWetTons), 0) 
       FROM Stocks.dbo.tblSurvey 
       WHERE tStockAreaID = 103
         AND tDateTimeOfSurvey BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20140228') + 
      (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tWetTons), 0) 
       FROM Stocks.dbo.tblSurvey 
       WHERE tStockAreaID = 181
         AND tDateTimeOfSurvey BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20140228')
    ) > 0
AND tStockAreaID IN (3,103,181) -- RAS, SOIL, DORB
AND tDateTimeOfSurvey BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20140228'
```

Many thanks, Pierre

Comment: please share your table DDLs, some sample data and a sample result explaining what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are your goals for simplifying?  That is, are you experiencing performance problems or incorrect results?

Comment: That seems trivial - why are there three subqueries when you could just have one with `tStockAreaID in (3,103,181)`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT MAX(tDateTimeOfSurvey) 
FROM Stocks.dbo.tblSurvey 
WHERE
    tStockAreaID IN (3,103,181) AND 
    tDateTimeOfSurvey BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20140228' 
HAVING SUM(tWetTons)>0
```